# Uncaught errors by .catch clause in Promise for JSON HTTP request

Tags: node.js, es6-promise, httpresponse

I have this function that collects JSON data from an API endpoint:

```
  export const getDataAPI = (token_id) => {
  const url = `https://api.url.com/tokens/` + token_id;
  const options = {method: 'GET', headers: {Accept: 'application/json'}};
  const request = fetch(url, options)
    .then(response => { if (response.status === 200) {
        return response.json();
      } else if ([404, 429, 500].includes(response.status)) {
        return response.status;
      } else {
        return response.json()
          .then(json => {
            console.log("Error: getDataAPI response status", response.status);
            throw json;
          })
      }
    })
    .catch(error => { throw error; });
  return Promise.resolve(request);
};
```

I have collected over 1.3M records with this function. I would like to catch any unexpected problems so I can gracefully pause for a few seconds and try again. But I came across 2 errors that were not sent to the .catch clause. Even if `response` is empty / null / undefined, I would expect at least to see the output of `console.log("Error: getDataAPI response status", response.status);`
These errors only happened once each.

```
undefined:1

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.json (file:///home/user/node_modules/node-fetch/src/body.js:149:15)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async file:///home/user/path/to/file.mjs:94:20
```

```
file:///home/user/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:108
            reject(new FetchError(`request to ${request.url} failed, reason: ${error.message}`, 'system', error));
                   ^

FetchError: request to https://api.url.com/tokens/29727608 failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (file:///home/user/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:108:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:442:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  erroredSysCall: 'read'
}
```

1. I don't understand why these errors were not caught by the function. Can someone please explain this?
2. How can I fix the function so it also catches this sort of errors?
3. What is the output I should be looking for to identify these errors, `SyntaxError` and `FetchError`? Is there a variable to monitor for error codes for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would expect at least to see the output of console.log("Error: getDataAPI response status", response.status);

That code isn't in a catch clause, it's in a `then` clause.

```js
return response.json()
          .then(json => {
            console.log("Error: getDataAPI response status", response.status);
            throw json;
          })
```

Your `catch` is simply rethrowing:

```js
.catch(error => { throw error; });
```

Which will give you an uncaught error.

You need to log/handle the error in the catch, not the `then` clause:

```js
 export const getDataAPI = (token_id) => {
  const url = `https://api.url.com/tokens/` + token_id;
  const options = {method: 'GET', headers: {Accept: 'application/json'}};
  const request = fetch(url, options)
    .then(response => { if (response.status === 200) {
        return response.json();
      } else if ([404, 429, 500].includes(response.status)) {
        return response.status;
      } else {
        console.log("Error: getDataAPI response status", response.status);
        // you can swallow the error here if you want, or try to parse it anyway
        return response.json()
      }
    })
    .catch(error => { 
       console.log('Handling error', error);
       throw error;
    });

  // wrapping the request in a Promise.resolve is also unnecessary 
  // return Promise.resolve(request);
  return request;
};
```

Comment: "don't rethrow or you'll get uncaught error" - but I want to stop the script when fetch returns an error I don't know about. And add a custom message with additional information so I can see what was the problem and write a workaround. The problem is situations where the status is not 200, 404, 429, 500 and STILL there is an exception that breaks the function without triggering the checks.

Comment: "You need to log/handle the error in the catch without rethrowing" - yes, but the error is not even reaching the .catch, otherwise I would see my custom error message and some output of the JSON retrieved from the endpoint.

Comment: "wrapping the request in a Promise.resolve is also unnecessary" - thanks, that was a good tip

Comment: @user2066480 I updated for rethrowing, you're welcome to do so, but my primary point and solution to your question stands: You shouldn't expect to handle/log an error in the `then` clause.

Comment: You are not getting the point: the .catch() clause is not capturing those 2 errors I indicated. console.log(error) inside the catch doesn't help, as the throw will repeat the same error message.

Comment: I am getting the point, I'm just disagreeing with you based on my experience with and understanding of how javascript works (12 years). Your original code has `.catch(error => { throw error; });` which does nothing. You can remove that line and get the exact same behavior. Catching and immediately rethrowing an error without doing anything else is for all intents and purposes, a no-op. I'm trying to help you solve your problem by showing you how to prove the catch is working, and you're rejecting my help.

Comment: Oh I got your point now. Took me a while to realize the checks inside the .then() clauses do not apply to 'upstream' errors that are raised even before a JSON string is composed. Thank you for your patience. I do want a throw to stop execution when an unforeseen error is raised, otherwise execution is transferred back to the main code and I get other errors because there is no JSON, and I'd rather have execution stopped cleanly if those situations happen again.

Answer (score 0):

With xdumaine's help I was able to figure out what I was doing wrong.

1. The errors were not triggering the `console.log` reporting because they were raised even before a JSON string could be composed.
2. The function was catching the errors, only there was nothing being done to them. I found [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SyntaxError) useful to better understand and test this. As a demonstration, here is a way to create an error and confirm the .catch() clause is handling it:

```
export const getDataAPI = (token_id) => {
  const url = `https://api.url.com/tokens/` + token_id;
  const options = {method: 'GET', headers: {Accept: 'application/json'}};
  const request = fetch(url, options)
    .then(response => { 
        throw new SyntaxError('Hello', 'someFile.js', 10);
        if (response.status === 200) {
        return response.json();
      } else if ([404, 429, 500].includes(response.status)) {
        return response.status;
      } else {
        return response.json()
          .then(json => {
            console.log("Error: getDataAPI response status", response.status);
            throw json;
          })
      }
    })
    .catch(error => { 
      console.log('Caught error', error.name);
      throw error; 
      });
  return request;
};
```

3. As demonstrated in the page linked above, `error.name` contains the name of the error.